# How to solve "AttributeError: 'FacetGrid' object has no attribute 'refline'" in Python

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, facet-grid

I want to create some charts like in this picture.
[image]

I have already succeeded to create it in google collab. Then, for some reason, I need to run my python script in jupyter notebook. But I got this error when I run it in jupyter notebook.

```
AttributeError: 'FacetGrid' object has no attribute 'refline'
```

My script to create the chart is like this:

```
plot_col=avg.drop(columns='crisis_day').columns

a = pd.melt(avg, id_vars=['crisis_day'], value_vars=plot_col)
g = sns.FacetGrid(a, col="variable",  col_wrap=3,  margin_titles=True)
g.map(sns.lineplot, "crisis_day","value")
for ax in g.axes.flatten(): 
    ax.tick_params(labelbottom=True)
g.refline(y=a["value"].mean())
g.refline(x=0)
plt.show()
```

Thankyou.

Comment: Upgrade your version of seaborn?

Comment: Thank you @BigBen. The issue has been solved.